# Confused about an matrix representing a color image

Tags: python, keras, computer-vision

I've just started learning basic knowledge about computer vision, when trying on some scripts of codes I encountered load_data() method to get dataset from cifar10. As you knowed one of its returns is x_train numpy array with shape (50000, 32, 32, 3), which is equal to 50000 color, 32x32 pixels images.
But I confused the tuple should be (50000, 3, 32, 32) rather than (50000, 32, 32, 3) because the matrix representing a color images (in this case ) is 3 2D matrices put on the top of each other. Is there something I'm mistaken here?

Comment: The red/green/blue components of each individual pixel are typically contiguous in memory.  There aren't three separate 2D matrices for the image, they are interlaced together.

Comment: It doesn’t matter what the order of the dimensions are, if you know how to interpret them.

Comment: NCHW vs NHWC, look it up. neural networks sometimes prefer CHW over HWC (convolution runs over the innermost dimensions). inference on neural networks commonly requires inputs to be transformed in this way. this is usually discussed in proper teaching materials.

Answer (score 1):

CIFAR-10 was created in 2009 ([https://www.cs.toronto.edu/~kriz/learning-features-2009-TR.pdf](https://www.cs.toronto.edu/%7Ekriz/learning-features-2009-TR.pdf)), around that same time the second major iteration of OpenCV got released. I suspect that the creators wanted to conform to the cv2 image channel format (`NHWC`). As cv already was the main workhorse for computer vision tasks.

Anyways, the order of the channels in the dataset are not that relevant. Even if you swap the axes around they still contain the exact same information.

What is important is that you input the right axis order to your specific framework so that the images can be interpreted correctly. You would need to reshape them anyways depending on which deep learning framework you use. Tensorflow uses `NHWC` (so does cv2) PyTroch uses `NCHW`.

This means that CIFAR-10 can be loaded directly for a Tensorflow-based CNN but needs to be reshaped for PyTorch.